pdfbox 3 encoding exception
I have a simple pdf file with an editable field and I should populate it with the info. Everything works perfectly fine when I use english characters but I have some fields that contains turkish characters. I have tried to add different fonts as I found different ways on the stackoverflow but none of them helped me. I also tried different pdfbox version 2.x.
My example code is like this:
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/pdf/template.pdf"))) {
      // Access the AcroForm
      PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

      PDType0Font load = PDType0Font.load(doc, new File("C:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf"));

      PDResources resources = acroForm.getDefaultResources();
      if (resources == null) {
        resources = new PDResources();
        acroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);
      }

      String fontName = resources.add(load).getName();

      String defaultAppearanceString = "/" + fontName + " 12 Tf 0 g";
      acroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);

      PDTextField myField = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField("field");
      myField.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);
      myField.getWidgets().get(0).setAppearance(null);
      myField.setValue("ŞŞ"); // Text with the Ş character

      // Save the updated document
      doc.save("target/SimpleFormWithCorrectFont.pdf");
    }
  }

This throws an error:
U+015E ('Scedilla') is not available in the font Helvetica, encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
I have tried different fonts and different methods to add font to pdfbox but the error is same.
What mistake do I have?

Please link to the template. Also call PDType0Font.load with the third parameter set to false. Please tell where you got that code, if it is from here I'll see if I can fix it.

What you might try (after making the change I mentioned) is to reload the file and then filling the field. The CreateSimpleFormWithEmbeddedFont example works fine but this one creates a PDF from scratch.

I found one that specifically mentions not to use subsetting, one fails despite using subsetting but this happens by a different usage than here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65701597/

@TilmanHausherr just created a simple pdf from [sejda] (https://www.sejda.com/) with a Forms > TextBox element. (Corporate laptop so vpn blocks everything cant share, sorry).
Setting third parameter to false did not change the result. My colleague came up with an idea of this,
defaultResources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helv"), font);
pDAcroForm.setDefaultResources(defaultResources);```
It worked!

That means you lose existing resources. This may or may not bring problems.

Now it's getting interesting: I was able to reproduce the problem with a PDF from sejda. It happens with 3.0.4-SNAPSHOT but it does not happen with 4.0 although the code is mostly the same except that 4.0 is jdk11.

The PDF looks strangely familiar, I think we have a ticket about this. It has a widget which has its own /DA entry. This one must be fixed as well with myField.getWidgets().get(0).getCOSObject().setString(COSName.DA, defaultAppearanceString);. Maybe me or Maruan (another team member) fixed this for 4.0.

I found it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5797 which references https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78258051/ so your question might be a duplicate. Going to sleep now LOL
